# How to fix broken windows in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, display

I recently installed Windows 7 on my laptop and got some display problem.  After using the computer for a while (e.g. 10 min), the edges of the windows break.  Here is a screenshot; open it in a new window to see more clearly:

[image]

The broken pixels stay even if I minimize/maximize/move the windows.  The problem can be temporarily solved by turning off Windows Aero and then turning it on; however the problem re-appears after a while.

Sometimes the interior of the window also breaks, but this happens less frequently.

It's a Dell Latitude E4200 with Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 4500MHD, running Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit. According to GPU-Z, the GPU is a 65nm GM45 running at 475MHz.

These are the drivers I've tried:

1. The one that was installed by default
2. The one from Dell's website (8.15.10.1855)
3. The latest one from Intel's website (15.​16.​2.​1986)

The version numbers are copied from their websites; I don't know why they use two versioning schemes.  And I'm pretty sure that I downloaded the right drivers (Win7 32-bit).

This never happens on Windows XP and Windows Vista (yes, right now it's a triple boot system).  Has anybody seen this before?  Any idea how to solve it?  I'm using Vista happily but I do want to be able to use 7 too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a similar thread over at the Dell Community forum:

**[Studio 1555 on Win7 showing smudged images](http://en.community.dell.com/forums/p/19301865/19582661.aspx)**

possible solutions: install the Vista driver or disable hardware virtualization in the BIOS

Comment: Thanks!  I've been using the laptop for 30 minutes and no smudged/broken windows come up!

Driver installed: Vista 32-bit from Dell (A03_R212487, 1/16/2009, 7.15.10.1637)

Comment: you're more than welcome :)

Comment: Unfortunately broken windows may still appear after sleep-resume (but rather rarely)